# How to make google not to index https for a wordpress webpage but still keep https support for wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, ssl, indexing, https, configuration

I have created a wordpress page, which have now been indexed by google. When searching for it using google I realized that the url which was indexed contains https and not http. This leads to a warning when I try to use the search result to go to the page.

How can I disable the https for my webpage part which contains the content? I still want to use https for wp-admin.

Or is there another way to avoid google to index the https url?

I checked the canonical in html and it is http, as following: